# Python pandas get value from dataframe and store in object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.7

Given the following pandas dataframe, how can I create an array of objects with all the values from the rows where the year is between 2020 and 2015? Assuming that there is data from 2020 to 2010 included in the dataframe.

```
    Year  Yield     Total   Amount      ExDate     PayDate  \
0   2020  3.09%  SGD 0.66  SGD0.33  2020-05-12  2020-05-26   
1   2020  3.09%  SGD 0.66  SGD0.33  2020-05-12  2020-05-26   
2   2019  7.02%   SGD 1.5   SGD0.3  2019-11-18  2019-11-29   
3   2019  7.02%   SGD 1.5   SGD0.3  2019-08-05  2019-08-20   
4   2019  7.02%   SGD 1.5   SGD0.3  2019-05-17  2019-05-31   
5   2019  7.02%   SGD 1.5   SGD0.6  2019-05-02  2019-05-17   
6   2018  7.95%   SGD 1.7   SGD0.6  2018-08-08  2018-08-21   
7   2018  7.95%   SGD 1.7   SGD0.6  2018-05-03  2018-05-15   
8   2018  7.95%   SGD 1.7   SGD0.5  2018-05-03  2018-05-15   
9   2017  2.95%  SGD 0.63  SGD0.33  2017-08-11  2017-09-27
```

Object:

```
class Object:
  def__init(self, year, yield_data, amount, total, ex_date, pay_date):
    self.year = year
    self. yield_data = yield_data
    self.total = total
    self.ex_date = ex_date
    self.pay_date = pay_date
    self.amount = amount
```

Comment: Can you explain `year must only appear once in the array of objects.`, since for the year `2019` there are different entries having different `ExdDate` and `PayDate`?

Comment: Yeah just realised that didnt make sense. Edited the question. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: @Sushanth No I edited it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this, [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) to filter the records between year's followed by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates) to get unique rows followed by
[`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the columns as per constructor argument's for unpacking later during object construction.

```
rename_cols = {'Year': 'year', 'Yield': 'yield_data', 'Amount': 'amount',
               'Total': 'total', 'ExDate': 'ex_date', 'PayDate': 'pay_date'}

data = (
    df[df.Year.between(2015, 2020)].drop_duplicates(subset=['Year']).
        rename(columns=rename_cols).to_dict(orient='records')
)

object_list = [Object(**x) for x in data]
```

---

```
for obj in object_list:
    print(f"Year : {obj.year}, Yield {obj.yield_data}")

Year : 2020, Yield 3.09%
Year : 2019, Yield 7.02%
Year : 2018, Yield 7.95%
Year : 2017, Yield 2.95%
```